# Python: merge two ordered lists, replacing elements conditionally

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, replace, merge

Beginner's question.

I have two ordered lists with the same order,

```
list_1=['de', 'de', 'de', '3']
list_2=['6', '5', '3', 'not']
```

so the n-th element of list_1 corresponds to the n-th element of list_2.

I want to merge the two lists while perserving their order. Moreover, the list resulting from the merge should consist entirely out of numbers, i.e.

```
merged_list=['6', '5', '3', '3']
```

Preferably, I merge by position in the list conditionally on string or numeric values. I have the same issue with other ordered lists, but with those lists I want to replace numeric values with string values. I.a. to solve my troubles with all the ordered lists I have I'd like to do something like:

```
replace element_n of list_i with element_n of list_j if element_n of list_i equals 'z'
```

where z is either a numeric value or a string value, dependent on the nature of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregates two list items:

```
>>> list_1 = ['de', 'de', 'de', '3']
>>> list_2 = ['6', '5', '3', 'not']
>>> zip(list_1, list_2)
<zip object at 0x1029e53c8>
>>> list(zip(list_1, list_2))
[('de', '6'), ('de', '5'), ('de', '3'), ('3', 'not')]
```

, and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if the given string is a number:

```
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True
>>> 'de'.isdigit()
False
```

By combining with [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you will get what you want:

```
>>> [a if a.isdigit() else b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
['6', '5', '3', '3']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Forgive me my ignorance, but <zip object at 0x1029e53c8> is Python output, not a command, right?

Comment: @LucSpan, You're right. `zip` returns a `zip object..` in python 3. It's iterable, but does not show it's content. So I put `list(zip(..)))` next line to show items it will yields once iterated.